# Linking issues with an exported function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a basic hello world program but fail in some linking issues.

in program.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "scanner.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string result = createScanner();
  cout << result << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

in scanner.h

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string createScanner();
```

in scanner.cpp

```
#include <scanner.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string createScanner() {
    return "hello world";
}
```

Using this CLI method:

```
clang++ -O3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -I./includes/ -I./compiler/  compiler/program.cpp  -o hej
```

And I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "createScanner()", referenced from:
      _main in program-45fd7b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: Add `scanner.cpp` to the command line too.

Comment: Isn't `-I./compiler/` enough? `scanner.h` and `scanner.cpp` is there?

Comment: add `scanner.cpp` and `#include "scanner.h"` in scanner.cpp

Comment: `-I` flag simply adds paths for the angle bracket style `#include`s. You always have to specify all cpp files you wish to compile.

Comment: Adding `-I./compiler` only adds that directory to the list of directories for searching files used in `#include` statements. It does not automatically compiler the `.cpp` files in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Add `scanner.cpp` to the command line**

```
clang++ -O3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -I./includes/ -I./compiler/  compiler/program.cpp compiler/scanner.cpp -o hej
```

**Option 2: Separate the compilation steps from the link step**

```
clang++ -c -O3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -I./includes/ -I./compiler/  compiler/program.cpp -o compiler/program.o
clang++ -c -O3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -I./includes/ -I./compiler/  compiler/scanner.cpp -o compiler/scanner.o
clang++ -O3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  compiler/program.o compiler/scanner.o -o hej
```

**Option 3: Use a Makefile**

Contents of `Makefile`:

```
CXX=clang++
CXXFLAGS= -O3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -I./includes/ -I./compiler/ 

hej: compiler/program.o compiler/scanner.o
    clang++ -O3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o $@ $^
```

Then just run:

```
make
```